# Get object context of a cached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, objectcontext

I want to manually create entity relationships with objects taken from cache.

```
Car car = Cache.GetCarById(1); // takes this from cache
SteeringWheel steeringWheel = Cache.GetSteeringWheelById(1); //takes this from DB 
                                                             //also saves in cache
car.SteeringWheel = steeringWheel;
```

On the above assignment

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

I have tried the following:

- return `steeringWheel` from cache after is saved there (thus making 2
  requests to cache for the same entity)
- detach each entity from it's
  own context before it gets cached

None of the above work. If I would be able to get the context for `car` I would attach `steeringWheel` to it, but... what context? Does the context gets saved with the object in cache and how do I get to it?

Note that I don't really need a context, I'm just displaying this data as is.

**LE**:
The context is a shared one across one http request, used from a static method

```
public static myEntities Context
    {
        get
        {
            string ocKey = "ocm_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(ocKey))
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ocKey, new myEntities());
            return HttpContext.Current.Items[ocKey] as myEntities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show how the Context is defined looks like you need to show more code `We are not mind readers ` here on SO

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added info about it, hope it helps

Comment: Actually detaching from context before caching works, there was a location were I wasn't doing it.